# iOS adobe air release build error, application cannot start

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I have an Adobe Air application built with Adobe Flash Builder 4.7, Flex 4.11 and Adobe Air 3.9 SDK.

I'm getting a build error and don't know why. From XCode:

```
**EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)**
```

I wonder what's the meaning of that error. I've googled it and some people say memory leak, or that the application using too much memory.

Is that the only explanation about that error? Do I have a problem with my compiler?

Code:
http://pastebin.com/daNa6Dfu --> the main mxml

http://pastebin.com/Edg2r8Ut --> mobileapplicationview.mxml

Comment: I think you're going to need to share a little code for people to be able to help

Comment: updated with the link to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://discussions.apple.com/message/18593139#18593139, XCODE saw that your application will make a device crash if run (probably the device would run out of memory, as you said).

See https://discussions.apple.com/message/18593139#18593139:

**'The crash is internal to the application. Only the developer can help you resolve it.'** by *Link Davis*

So a memory leak is the most likely explanation if it was compiled with *Adobe Air*.

**[EDIT]**
It is also good to check crash reports left by XCode to see the problem.  Also, does it crash when you test it on your device, or how did you compile your application?  That could also be important.

Also, are there infinite loops in your code?  Make sure there is none of that and/or duplicate lines of code:

[Strange Errors resulting in EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589421/strange-errors-resulting-in-exc-bad-access-sigsegv/4589842#4589842):

**It's weird I got this error, and I went through countless solutions.  Turned out, I had duplicated a line of code by accident. Just make sure when you duplicated, there is not code interfering with each other.** by *TheSlope*

Most importantly, make sure your device doesn't have more RAM than the required amount of RAM an app can use.  For example, a memory leak could occur in your app without you knowing, use your app and check settings to see how much it uses.

Comment: Yes, it crashed on device with release build but with debug .ipa it didn't crash.
Thanks for the link I'll check it!

Comment: @dev0x10 Your welcome, but there is a way to thank me even more, by accepting my answer and pressing the blank check mark.

Comment: you got your mark and surprisingly my mark is the 700th for you lol
I still have no idea what's going on after read those links, what I'm doing now is cleaning the codes and try again

Comment: @dev0x10 Kk, but maybe the device you tested on had more memory than the Apple's requirements?

Comment: what you mean with more memory than the apple's requirement?
I'm using iPAD 2 for testing

Comment: @dev0x10 Like it contains more RAM.  Did you check how much it has under **usage** in settings?  I think it's located somewhere else in iOS7.  For example, your iPad 2 has 40 free GB, while apple's testing device only has about 5GB left, and that's how much GB your app uses.  Use your app and check settings to see how much RAM your app uses (on your iPad 2).